# How can i enable both services i.e., Direct Payment and Express Checkout on Paypal live US business account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Recently I had implemented **Recurring Payments API** using the following payment methods:

- **Direct Payment**
- **Express Checkout**

All was working fine on **Sandbox account**. But on **Live account** when i enable one payment solution like **Express Checkout** then service for **Direct Payment** is disabled and vice-versa. How can i enable both above mentioned payment methods/solutions for **Recurring Payments**?

Comment: How can i enable both services on Live Paypal Account?

Answer (score 0):

You are requested to go to the link below to upgrade your US PayPal account to the Pro account.
https://www.paypal-business.com/paypal-pro
After that you are able to integrate Direct Payment for Recurring Payments.
You can also refer to the link below.
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/general/DPRPLaunch-outside